# " ! You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run"

Tags: steam

The libraries in particular that I am missing are libpipewire-0.3.so.0, and libxcb-res.so.0. I don't know to much about coding and terminal, so something to copy and paste would be good. I think it started becuase I didn't have enough storage, (resolved) but now I need to know how to fix it. I tried uninstalling and re installing, but it didn't work. and yes, I have turned it off and on again.

Comment: You're missing the basic starting point, which is what OS & release you're using.  Please also copy/paste into your question actual messages (*package info is very helpful*).

Answer (score 0):

when you ask a question its best to list your Ubuntu version (the answer may be different depending on it, run `lsb_release -a` to find it), and you can copy and paste the actual terminal output into the question.

assuming your running 64bit ubuntu 22.04:

first you should check for and install updates with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

to make sure you have all the libraries your supposed to have.

if that does not fix it then you can manually install the 32 bit binaries with:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt install libpipewire-0.3-0:i386
sudo apt install libxcb-res0:i386
```

this adds the architecture for 32 bit systems, and installs the 2 listed packages 32 bit versions